# xargs -I# showing unexpected behavior - why?

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I'd like to zip a whole bunch of folders which are in a certain directory, creating one zip file per folder. To do that, I use the following command:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -I@ zip -r @.zip @
```

This works as expected.

However, by accident, I noticed a behavior which I didn't expect when I used `#` as the replace string instead of `@`:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -I# zip -r #.zip #

zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)

zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)

... and so on (the same message repeated for every folder)
```

`#` normally opens a comment, so it's clear that things go wrong here. But I would have expected that the command line then actually becomes `find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -I`, because everything from (and including) the first `#` is a comment and is stripped off.

However, it obviously executes the `zip` command. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment (in the `bash` shell), is introduced by the `#` character.  But this only happens if the `#` character is unquoted, and the first character in a word (token).

If `#` is quoted or occurs as a character other than the first character in a word, this will not introduce a comment.

Compare:

```bsh
$ echo this is a #comment
this is a
$ echo this is not a#comment
this is not a#comment
$ echo not a '#comment'
not a #comment
```

In interactive shells, comments are *never* introduced if the `interactive_comments` shell option is turned off (it's on by default).

```bsh
$ shopt -u interactive_comments
$ echo not a #comment
not a #comment
```

Comment: not just Bash, but pretty much all sh-like shells take `#` as starting a comment. It looks to be POSIX too, point 9 in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03 (Zsh also has `setopt [no]interactivecomments`)

Comment: @ilkkachu I wrote it that way because in the `zsh` shell, whatever character is the 3rd character in `$HISTCHARS` starts a comment, and I didn't want to get bogged down in the particularities of other shells.